# Kinect Face Tracking Gestures

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I working on [Kinect Face Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx)

I want to implement facial expressions. Currently I have:

1. AU1 – **Jaw Lowerer** from AUs
2. AU2 – **Lip Stretcher** from Aus

I want to implement other gestures like:

1. Right eye blink
2. Left eye blink
3. Both eye blink

And other gestures described here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NFsea7CoxQ
- http://futuretechblog.com/?p=71

I have a face model points:

[image: Face model]

**But what is the best way to do this?**

Now my one idea is to calculate distance between specyfic points. For example:

```
var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(facePoints[10].X - facePoints[35].X, 2) + Math.Pow(facePoints[10].Y - facePoints[35].Y, 2));
```

Grab statistic of gestures to Exel graph and do like this:

```
if(disnace<calculatedValue)
```

**My Questions are:**

1. My idea is correct? Can I do this with my idea?
2. Do you know any dll do detcet face gestures for Kinect C# SDK.?
3. Do you have any samples of detect gestures?
4. Do you have any other ideas how to detect gestures?

Thanks! :)

Comment: As the accepted answer indicates, the primary thrust of this question is specific enough to be answerable.  Closing it really serves no productive purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is rather correct. I have developed some gestures myself for a couple applications, like an eat gesture, call gesture, swipe gesture etc.

You need to do a lot more than just checking distance. You need to check the distance relative with time as well, together with some kind of error margin.

If you would like to bind actions to blinking then you can't just execute the action the moment your distance < calculatedValue, because people blink a lot. You will need to make some kind of gesture finder that keeps track of the current distance for X-amount of seconds and is only triggered if the distance < calculatedValue for X-amount of seconds with an error margin of 90% for example.

You can do this with your idea but don't expect it to work 100% of the time. The distance between your eyes and eyebrows are different for every person. So you will either have to 'initialize' a normal posture for every new user or try to get an average distance in normal resting mode and work with the differences if he blinks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some experience messing around with such things before. Mostly in OpenCV, but the ideas are still the same. Your approach is essentially correct, but I found that adding two things to the detection algorithm improved it many fold.

Firstly, add an element of time into the detection criteria. How long triggers should detect a gesture before the gesture event fires is very important to the user experience. I would suggest that you have a running average of the gesture detection's local results (say over x many frames), along with a running average for each gesture event being fired. Think of it like stochastic prediction models. (it's not, but I like to think of user experience issues in that light. I find it speeds up how many prototypes I have to build to get it feeling right.)
Whenever I need to come up with ideas for solving issues in this ilk, I always turn to Technical Analysis websites. These are smart people who spend all day trying to visualize trends in nosy data. Might be of some help for you.

Secondly, you will need to have some sort of noise filter. I always start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

Good luck!